# Authorization Required - While accessing VF page of managed package on sites

Tags: managed-package, appexchange

We have developed a managed package and as a part of package it has VF pages, extension classes, custom objects etc.

When the VF pages of the package are accessed on the developed environment they seem to be working fine. But when on the environment where the package is installed it gives out a Authorization required message.

My initial thought was it could be a permissions issue, Checked the site guest user profile and it had all requisite permission on the objects and VF pages but there was no class from the managed package available to be added in the `Enable Apex classes Access`
section of the profile. I am assuming the classes do get added automatically when the VF pages are added. Correct me if i am wrong here

On further examination on the cause, when we access this VF page directly from salesforce environment and not from sites environment, we do get the message `The installed managed class xxxx.xxxclass is not visible` . We are getting this message from a system administrator profile. Admin profile should have all the access so this cant be an issue of permissions.

All of these work perfectly as expected on the developing environment. I am not sure on the next steps to identify what could be the cause.

The class which is having this issue is a extension class.